# Setting node path and allowing to run as sudo

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sudo, node.js

I've got a raspberry pi that I'm running node on. I followed this guide http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi to install node.

When I setup the `NODE_JS_HOME`, I can run node from the command line, but not sudo node, and I need to be sudo to access GPIO.

I also seem to need to re-enter the NODE_JS_HOME in my .bash_profile every time I open a new terminal window. I'm hoping that I can set node globally and be able to run `sudo node` form the command line, right from start-up.

Comment: what is the error when running sudo node?  command not found, or not allowed to be sudo?

Comment: running `sudo node' returns `sudo: node: command not found`, I've now got node loading by default as per @fede.evol

Comment: you should be able to run su -c 'node' or sudo /path/to/node.  try them

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the NODE_JS_HOME variable in your */etc/profile* file. That file contains system wide settings that will therefore be applied to every shell execution.

Comment: Thanks fede, I now can load node automatically, but I still can't load using `sudo node`, I get the error `sudo: node: command not found`

Comment: I guess you're missing the PATH part aswell. In the doc you refeer it shows to put also the PATH (PATH=$PATH:$NODE_JS_HOME/bin). You should put also that in /etc/profile (of course after the NODE_JS_HOME definition)

Comment: I have both the definition and the PATH in my /etc/profile, but no luck running node via sudo

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling node and re-installing via

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg node_latest_armhf.deb
```

After that `sudo node` ran perfectly, without having to set-up any profiles

Answer (score 0):

To get sudo to work on normal linux, I had to make these links:

```
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
  ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/node-waf /usr/bin/node-waf
```

Not sure if they'll make it work in raspberry pi too, but its probably worth a try.